# Django and Common Access Cards (CAC)

Tags: django, pki, django-authentication, cac

A web app written in Python is planned, Django is a leading contender as framework.

One requirement is CAC access, wihout the need to hand enter username and password.  From what I can tell, CAC access is not part of the "batteries" included with Django.

As a monolithic framework (not necessarily a bad attribute) Django has a rep for being high-maintenance once you modify the core.  Can I easily add CAC access to a Django site?  Can it be easily maintained thereafter?

Or maybe we should consider a different Python framework?

FYI.. interesting presentation on CAC access [link](http://www.slideshare.net/rbulling/enabling-web-apps-for-dod-security-via-pkicac-enablement-forgemil-case-study)

Comment: Did you happen to get this working?  I'm looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to modify the core to enable this. Django supports third-party authentication backends and they're fairly easy to write - you just need to support two methods, `get_user` and `authenticate`. So your implementation just needs to perform these operations using your CAC interface, and all will work as usual.

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/) for details.

**Edited after other answers** I don't know why people are saying this is difficult in Django. Yes, many parts of Django are difficult to customise. But this is one particular part that is made *very* easy. I've written several authentication backends in Django and they are not only really simple, but they "just work" with the rest of the framework, including the admin. There isn't any need to modify anything else to get this to work.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  I'll give it a shot and hope for the "and all will work as usual."

Answer (score 0):

I just did this today by subclassing django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware and changed the header property to the one I had set in my apache conf.  I just added the django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend and my middleware to the settings and it works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Extending contrib.auth is a pain in the neck. It's the single worst thing in django. If you need highly customized auth backend, i would suggest using a different framework.